# Régua de Orientação

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Em alguns editores possuimos uma régua de orientação na qual podemos realizar algumas configurações como por exemplo
 o espaçamento entre o texto e a folia.

Preciso produzir algo como:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atualmente utilizo um Editor de textos chamado [Summernote](http://summernote.org/#/), ele me retorna todo o texto em html,
para o usuário fazer a impressão deste documento transformo este html em um pdf com [mpdf](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=306).

Exemplo de uma orientação do mpdf:

```
 $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L');
```

**Dúvidas:**

1° Como posso adicionar uma regua para fazer orientação?

2° É possivel obter o resultado sem utilizar a regua?

3° Existe outra forma de solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que no summernote ficará difícil implementar este recurso, pois a finalidade com que foi desenvolvido foi outra, apesar de algumas vezes colocar spans com css inline no código, ele não lida com o CSS de uma página inteira.

Para gerar PDF tem que verificar se a classe utilizada interpreta CSS principalmente para arquivos externos, a maioria aceita apenas CSS inline. E caso aceitem, você pode adicionar campos no formulário para que o usuário configure a página, definindo margem, orientação da página, e tipo de folha.

Faltará apenas a possibilidade de controlar o recuo ou o avanço de um trecho específico do texto, por exemplo uma citação que fica distanciado da borda da página. Para isso é possível desenvolver algum plugin para o summernote ou outro editor que aumentará ou diminuirá as margens laterais do parágrafo, adicionando a formatação direto na tag, ficando algo assim:

```
<p style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;>Parágrafo</p>
```

Mas caso queira desenvolver algum editor destes para impressão ou geração de PDF aqui está algumas dicas.

[É possivel formatar a visualização da página durante a edição para que fique mais real](http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/LFAes/)

Para criar um CSS específico para impressão utilize os media types.

```
@media screen {
    …
}
@media print {
    …
}
```

Ou para arquivos separados:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" media="print"/>
```

Definindo o tamanho da página

```
@media print {
    @page {
        // size: auto; Para adaptar a posição configurada no browser.
        // size: portrait; Para página em posição retrato.
        // size: landscape; Para página em posição paisagem.
        size: 8.5in 11in;  // largura altura

        // E para configurações específicas quando o browser encontrar uma
        // determinada tag.
        @page rotated { size : landscape }
        table { page : rotated }

        // Para configurar páginas de impressão frente e verso
        @page :left {
            margin-left: 4cm;
            margin-right: 3cm;
        }
        @page :right {
            margin-left: 3cm;
            margin-right: 4cm;
        }

        // Configurando a primeira página
        @page :first {
            margin-top: 10cm;
        }

        // Controlando quebra de página de acordo com uma determinada tag
        // auto: Definição de quera de página padrão
        // right: Quebra para a página da direita em impressão frente e verso
        // left: Quebra para a página da esqueda em impressão frente e verso
        // avoid: Evita que quebra página
        // always: Sempre quebra página
        h1 { page-break-before : right }
        h2 { page-break-after : avoid }

        // Para evitar que elementos se quebrem no meio
        table { page-break-inside : avoid }

        // Para evitar páginas com poucas linhas apenas, da pra definir
        // quantas linhas a mais serão permitidas por página até que a
        // quebra de linha ocorra, ou quantas linhas mínimas no topo da 
        // página são permitidas antes de que a quebra de linha ocorra.
        @page {
            orphans: 4; // Define o número de linhas no fim da página.
            widows:2; // Define o número de linhas no topo da página.
        }
    }
}
```

Outras dicas para formatação da página para impressão podem ser encontradas em http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Para evitar que o Browser adicionem as informações de cabeçalho e no rodapé:

```
<html moznomarginboxes mozdisallowselectionprint>
```

Porem só funciona em versões do Firefox mais recentes.

Comment: +1, boa resposta, vou estar testando cada um destes detalhes, obrigado!